# Why Java not export PDF with font configured in .jrxml file in jasper studio?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I using Jasper to export PDF file in java spring. First, I created report template in Jasper studio, change font as I expect and it display seem good. After that, I use this .jrxml template to export PDF file in java, but the problem is the font of this file is not corresponding to font I have configured. I have tried to change config font in template but it seem not have any effect on java application.

This lead to error when I use Vietnamese like that:

```
original text: "Chi phí phát triển thuê bao mới"
rendered text: "Chi phí phát trin thuê bao mi"
```

This is my java code:

```
public static void createPdfReport() {
    try{
      final InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/abc/JaspersoftWorkspace/MyReports/test_table.jrxml"));
      final JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
      final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
      List<Employee> employees = getSource();
      JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employees);
      parameters.put("ItemDataSource", itemsJRBean);
//      final JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getSource());
      final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
      final String filePath = "/home/abc/Documents/Draft/";
      JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, filePath + "test.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Can anyone give me a clue to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the machine that you deploy the java system does not have fonts that you config. Please review this article on stack overflow for more understanding: [What is the jasperrepots-fonts jar for and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184408/what-is-the-jasperrepots-fonts-jar-for-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I have use dejavu font, which is available on my OS (I use Linux and check by fc-list command). Therefore, I'm afraid that it isn't my problem.

Comment: You need to add dejavu font to the machine that you deploy the program or add it in to jasperreports-fonts.jar